# JavaScript match numbers that are not zero or start with zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that I'm trying to ONLY allow numbers like:

`1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 24 etc`

and NOT `0, 01, etc`

```
if (!$(this).text().match(/^[1-9][0-9]/g)) {


}
```

Is this correct? As it doesn't allow numbers like 1, 2, 3 but is 11, 12 etc

Comment: Can you not just check whether the first character is `0`?  Or do you need to allow `0.5`, etc?

Comment: would running parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) solve your problem?

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle No only whole numbers, so checking for leading zero would work

Comment: Should `230345734872590343598340952342342483485` match?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify a `*` after second `[0-9]` to match zero or more digits. In addition to one digit numbers, this will also fail to match more than two digit numbers. Correct regular expression is `^[1-9][0-9]*`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Replace ()

```
if (!$(this).text().replace(/^(-?)0+/,'').match(/[1-9]?[0-9]*/))
```